# WinDivert 1.0.5 DivertRecv() Method Get last error 998

Tags: c#, c++, wfp

I have been write my c# wrapper for WFP (windows filtering platform ) , i use   WinDivert 1.0.5  , 
this import syntax

```
[DllImportAttribute("WinDivert.dll", EntryPoint = "DivertRecv",SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool DivertRecv([InAttribute()] System.IntPtr handle,
                                                  [OutAttribute()]  System.IntPtr pPacket, 
                                                  [InAttribute()]  uint packetLen,
                                      [ OutAttribute()]  System.IntPtr pAddr,
                                      [OutAttribute()]  System.IntPtr readLen);
```

and this function call syntax

```
if( DivertRecv(handle, Ppacket, (uint)(8 * packet.Length-1),
                 Paddr,  Ppacket_len) == false)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("warning: failed to read packet {0} .", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Press any key to Exit ...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

but the function return false with every call , and the GetLastWin32Error() get error code 998 . plz help me .

Comment: Can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296106/windivert-in-c-sharp) and help me out. I think I might have the same problem as the one you solved.

Comment: @SecurityCrazy it'd be super cool if you shared your C# wrapper for windivert. I'm in the process of struggling to put one together. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

998 = ERROR_NOACCESS (Invalid access to memory location).  This is likely caused by passing an invalid pointer to DivertRecv.

Is the pPacket parameter a pointer to a pre-allocated buffer of size packetLen?

Comment: sir Basil thank for reply ... i declare pPacket as th follow :-
  IntPtr Ppacket = new IntPtr(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PACKET)));
and the PACKET is  type of  struct declared in my project ..

Comment: I don't think that declaration is correct.  It just creates an IntPtr whose bit value is the integer result of the sizeof.  It is not allocating any memory.

Comment: Dear Basil , I need to tell you that .. you are great programmer and i do not know how can i thank you .. can you help me in this problem in your examples , error in send tcp rest packet 1237 ..

Comment: The 1237 error is usually caused by incompatible security software installed on your system.  You can search stackoverflow and see a few other people have this problem.

Comment: Dear Basil .. i disable my Antivirus but nothing change .. i saw your comment in other question that have the same problem .. but the 1237 is not the rely  win32 error code , it is translate to user mode to 1237 error code . but it is depend on NTSTAT error code from kernel mode > when i run your example at 1st time it is work without

Comment: any error . but in the second run after the machine is restarted the error is happen .

Comment: i search about this in some site and i found that . the error comes from wrong packet header or from user mode program   error when read registry key .. cane you tell me what is registry key your driver is depend on .. may be my English language is bad . but assume that you are understand what i say .. thank you very much for your replay.

Comment: The WinDivert driver does not directly depend on any registry key.  As for the underlying frameworks, I am not sure.

Comment: Basil, do you see chance to use a .NET managed host process for the hooks what WinDivert uses? Maybe it is not only to call the WinDivert API, but it is about the .NET managed host process...

Comment: Sorry but I don't use .NET so I can't help you out.

Comment: @Basil do you recommend creating a C++/CLI wrapper for WinDivert ? The purpose is to make it easier than PInvoke, to call user-mode routines from C#. Please take a look at this (long) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296106/windivert-in-c-sharp). It would be kind of you to have the patience to help me out.

Comment: I can't really help as I have no experience with C#.